# Augmented reality, projection of longitude and latitude on camera view

Tags: android, gps, augmented-reality

I am supposed to develop an adroid app that displays a picture on the camera view, when you point the camera in the right direction, 
representing a point in the sky with given latitude, longitude and altitude.
I found an algorithm for doing this here:
[Perspective Projection in Android in an augmented reality application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619104/perspective-projection-in-android-in-an-augmented-reality-application)

But I am having trouble to understand it and implemented it. Does someone have code example on this subject?

Comment: This [link][1] would give you a headstart.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190414/find-set-of-latitudes-and-longitudes-using-users-current-latitude-longitude-an?rq=1

Comment: These are the topics, where your math teacher could say. "Now you know, why you need mathematics" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://beyondar.com/platform) project will help you, it is called [BeyondAR](http://beyondar.com/platform)

Comment: the question was _how_ not which tool/framework ... Also, looks like you are spreading the link ... could smell spammy ...